# How to mount local folder with mount_afp in OS X 10.6.8

Tags: macos, snow-leopard

I tried to use `mount_afp afp://user:111@127.0.0.1/home ~/Documents` to mount the `~/Documents` folder to the shared folder, but it shows the error like below:

> mount_afp: AFPMountURL returned error 62, errno is 62

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Mac OS X allows you to connect to your own machine for AFP mounts.  For example, if you go to the Finder, select Go > Connect to Server, and type "afp://localhost", it puts up a dialog saying:

> **Connection Failed**
>   The server "localhost" is available on your computer. Access the volumes and files locally.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a solution to your problem, but I suggest you to create alias instead.

It's doing exactly what you wanted to do.

But if you still want to afp to local machine, read [here](http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-715430.html).

It involves creating a SSH tunnel to trick OS X of connecting to another machine while it's just localhost.

```
ssh -L 1548:localhost:548 mypowerbook.local
```

1548 is the fake port, and mypowerbook.local is your machine's host name. You do need root for this.

Then connect to the afp server with "localhost:1548", and it should work.

But, it's an outdated post, I'm not sure if it will work. Anyway, good luck!